# Postgresql database read only mirror

Tags: database, postgresql

What I need is basically to create read-only mirror of remote database on my local computer. It would be also neat if the mirror would be able to periodically update itself.

Version of the database is `Postgresql 9.3`.

The reason for doing this is that I need to perform selects to that database and on my internet connection it takes ages.

I have found [this article](http://www.rassoc.com/gregr/weblog/2013/02/16/zero-to-postgresql-streaming-replication-in-10-mins/) but it requires access to that remote server which I currently do not have. So is there some way of doing it without having direct access to the server? What I have is only db name, domain, port, username and password.

Comment: if you don't have direct access to the db server, then you can't really be sure your copy will be accurate (or even possible to do).

Comment: Do you sometimes have any access to the database ? With a remote direct connection or via some other file-based transfert ?

Comment: Unfortunately, as I wrote, what I have is db name, domain, port, username and password. Nothing else :-( And what's more, when I tried the approach described in the article, I linked, I got `FATAL:  no pg_hba.conf entry for replication connection from host`. However I really need only read-only access. So I thought there would be some other way around.

Comment: What is your operating system ? Do you have any scripting language available locally ?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04. Locally I can do and install practically everything.

Comment: You'll likely need shell access in order to do what you're doing, unless you're OK exporting the entire database to a file, then re-importing it locally, which is probably unfeasible.

Comment: Well I guess I could probably do that and put some script to cron to do it periodically but the database is quite big (~1 Gb) so I would rather avoid that.

Answer (score 3):

If you only have access to the database with username and password, I would create a simple script that drops the current local database and repopulate it from the freshly recovered database dump.

The script would look like this

```
#!/bin/bash
REMOTE_PSQL_OPTIONS="-h <remote_host> -p <remote_port> -U <remote_user>"
LOCAL_PSQL_OPTIONS="-h localhost -p <local_port> -U <local_user>"


# retrieve the database locally 
echo "Remote database fetch"
pg_dump $REMOTE_PSQL_OPTIONS <remote_db_name> > /tmp/my_db.sql

# install locally
echo "Local install in temporary database"
psql $LOCAL_PSQL_OPTIONS postgres "CREATE DATABASE my_tmp_db"
psql $LOCAL_PSQL_OPTIONS my_tmp_db -f /tmp/my_db.sql

# switch databases
echo "Installing the new database version"
psql $LOCAL_PSQL_OPTIONS postgres 
# backup the current local db
psql $LOCAL_PSQL_OPTIONS postgres "ALTER DATABASE current_db_name RENAME TO current_db_name_backup;"
# rename the tmp db to the expected local database name
psql $LOCAL_PSQL_OPTIONS postgres "ALTER DATABASE my_tmp_db RENAME TO current_db_name;"

# if you trust this script, uncomment this line that clean old backups
# psql $LOCAL_PSQL_OPTIONS postgres "DROP DATABASE current_db_name_backup;"
```

Hope that helps.

If you could had any ssh access, you could gzip the sql dump before transfert but for now this is your only choice.